# how and on what is a physical alarm clock programmed

Tags: assembly

i do hope this question fits here, otherwise sorry.

I have a physical alarm clock (5$) which has been programmed for snooze, light effects, etc.

Generally, all these devices like calculator, hi-fi-system (with display), etc.
**How and in which language did they programm them?**

Do all of them require a small processor? ...or is there even a small brother of a processor which is so damn cheap and fast to do the easy job?

Can/Could these devices been reprogrammed by us for customization? Which programming language?

it really makes me wonder.

thanks for your time

Comment: C# and assembler don't mix, why both tags?

Comment: A clock uses a dedicated integrated circuit to control its functions. The quartz crystal gives the cycle, a series of dividers convert to seconds, a counter accumulates the elapsed time and a last circuit manages the led display, alarm and special features. It's hard wired cannot be reprogrammed. Calculators have a small integrated circuit to manage all functions. More advanced devices have programmable micro-controllers and the machine language program is stored in a ROM.

Comment: @ed hi, like i told i did not know the language exactly. with these languages i went back as much to the roots of machine language i knew so far. sorry for my lack of knowledge. thx 4 dismissing c# if you want.

Comment: I am a systems programmer and I can guarantee you that they aren't programmed in C#.  Look into microprocessors, and small ones at that for something like an alarm clock.  No managed languages being used in the real world on devices like these.  Hell, it could be implemented purely in hardware for that matter.

Comment: @ed ty for your knowledge. i don't understand how this could be done hardwarewise. are there any links for info you got?

Comment: well, think about; what does software do?  It ultimately generates pulses of electricity down circuits.   That's it.  Theoretically you could do it *all* in hardware, it just becomes really complicated really quickly and software is a better alternative.

Comment: E.g. the NTE2062 IC implements everything in one chip without programming with the option to take the clock from a 50/60 Hz power supply to save an oscillator. http://www.nteinc.com/specs/2000to2099/pdf/nte2062.pdf It costs about 3 USD/pc, but I am sure there are much cheaper solutions < 10 ct/pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not programmed in C#, that's for sure :) There's always an assembly language, of course. For higher-level language support, C is quite popular. The larger and more complex the chip, the more different compilers will be available for it.

[Here](http://home.ict.nl/~fredkrom/pe0fko/g8voi_guide/) is a link to a simple tutorial on how to program one of the many, many kinds of available small microprocessors. Larger cousins of these tiny Atmel processors form the heart of the [Arduino,](http://www.arduino.cc/) a very easy-to-use prototyping board that you can program in a simple Java-like language that's compiled down to Atmel assembler.

We all have to start someplace.

Comment: is arm already to advanced for simplest devices? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture

Comment: ARM is a 32-bit chip with many advanced features; it's (obviously) suitable for laptops, smartphones, etc: *real computers*. Simple embedded systems like we're talking about here use 8 or 16-bit processors without the complicated bits -- like a virtual memory controller -- that architectures like ARM have.

Comment: arm is becoming competitive in the microcontroller market, for the same price and size you can get significantly more processing power, and with the cortex-m0 for example they are making them lower power.  ARM based will give you the advantage of a larger pool of developers and better development tools, in addition to the processing power relative to size/power.

Comment: Arduino is pretty much the opposite of the ease/efficiency curve from these alarm-clock things. Probably they are 8 bitters with 128 bytes of mem. The rest is overkill

Answer (score 0):

It may possibly contain a custom ASIC in which everything is "hard coded" in a language such as VHDL. Why? Cost savings during mass production.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not programmed, if it is mass produced surely is an ASIC (Application Specific Integrated Circuit) in wich the function of the clock is hard wired in the silicon die. It was probably prototyped in some FPGA (programmable) and then converted into an ASIC.